# Delegate for an Action< ref T1, T2>

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates

I'm trying to create a delegate of a static method which takes a ref argument.  Please don't ask why I'm doing such a cockamamie thing.  It's all part of learning how .Net, C#, and reflection work and how to optimize it.

My code is:

```
    public struct DataRow
    {

        private double t;
        static public void Cram_T(ref DataRow dr, double a_t)
        {
            dr.t = a_t;
        }
    }
 ''''
  Type myType = typeof(DataRow);
  MethodInfo my_Cram_T_Method = myType.GetMethod("Cram_T");
  var myCram_T_Delegate = 
         Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<DataRow, Double>),      
                                 my_Cram_T_Method) 
                                 as Action<DataRow, Double>;
```

This gives me a binding error because (I think) the generic action doesn't match the method.

Inspecting the value of Cram_T_Method in the watch window gives

```
{Void Cram_T(DataRow ByRef, Double)}
```

I then tried using the ref keyword in the Action:

```
  var myCram_T_Delegate = 
         Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<ref DataRow, Double>),         
                                 my_Cram_T_Method) 
                                 as Action<ref DataRow, Double>;
```

But this won't compile. The C# compiler chokes at the token "ref".

What is the right way to create this delegate?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Create your own delegate type:

```
delegate void MyAction(ref DataRow dataRow, double doubleValue);
```

And use `MyAction` in place of `Action<ref DataRow, Double>` -- which, as you've noted, doesn't compile.

Comment: Which brings limitations to inner methods.

Comment: What are these limitations ?

Answer (score 28):

@Ben M has the right idea, although you could make it more generic:

```
public delegate void RefAction<T1, T2>(ref T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
```

The problem has nothing to do with delegates as such - it's just that you can't use `ref` when you specify a type argument.

In theory the "it's by ref or not" is part of the type information (hence `Type.IsByRef`) but you can't specify it like that.

Frankly I'm not at all sure what would happen if you tried to create a `List<ref int>` via reflection, for example - I would *hope* that an exception would be thrown... it's not a very sensible concept :)

EDIT: I've just tried it:

```
Type refInt = typeof(int).MakeByRefType();
Type refIntList = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(refInt);
```

Throws an error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: The type 'System.Int32&' may
not be used as a type argument.
```

Comment: Type arguments must be types whose values are convertible to object. Managed and unmanaged pointer types don't meet that requirement.

Comment: Well I never. Fascinating. For once, I *don't* think it'll be worth including that in C# in Depth. Maybe as a note...

Comment: This works but the list commentary is irrelevant.
     public delegate void RefGenAction<T1, T2>(ref T1 arg1, T2 arg2);
    var myCram_TDelegate = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(RefGenAction<DataRow, Double>), myType.GetMethod("Cram_T")) as RefGenAction<DataRow, Double>;

Comment: @Max Yaffe: In what way is the list commentary irrelevant? It's making the point that you can never use "ref Foo" as a generic type argument, whether it's for a delegate or not.

Comment: The VB.NET equivalent, adding a type constraint to type T1: `Public Delegate Sub RefAction(Of T1 As Class, T2)(ByRef arg1 As T1, ByVal arg2 As T2)`