# How to use a fragment of a method many times in a method?

Tags: c#

I'd been searching for it for like an hour and I didn't find any result on that:
When I am programming some methods I pretty often run into situation when a method needs to repeat some fragments. I know it is bad to just copy these.

What I want to do is to get some code into for example `Action<>` or `Func<>` and use it in different places in my code. The problem is, I cannot use any `this.` properties. Visual studio suggest to declare something like `var thisForAction = this;` and use this local variable. Is it really the only way around?

Thanks in advance :)

// EDIT: That's my solution so far

```
struct TransformationMod
{
    public Nullable<float> Rotation;
    public Nullable<Vector2D> Position;
    public Nullable<Vector2> Scale;

    public struct Origin
    {
        public Vector2D Point; // if not Absolute, then  0 <= x,y <= 1
        public bool HasAbsoluteCoordinates;
    }
    public Nullable<Origin> RotationOrigin;
    public bool Absolute;

    public Transformation Perform(Transformation On)
    {         
        Transformation result = On;
        float rotationBefore = result.Rotation;

        Action<Origin?> HandleRotationOrigin =
            delegate(Origin? RotationOrigin)
            {
                if (RotationOrigin.HasValue)
                {
                    // We need to change position to a new one - produced by rotation around a spacified origin

                    // http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2012/11/24/GameDev-math-recipes-Rotating-one-point-around-another-point.aspx

                    // counting center of rotation
                    Vector2D center;
                    center = RotationOrigin.Value.Point;

                    if (!RotationOrigin.Value.HasAbsoluteCoordinates)
                    {
                        // check with lines below if() and the link provided. Also from stackoverflow:
                        /*
                                float s = sin(angle);
                                float c = cos(angle);

                                // translate point back to origin:
                                p.x -= cx;
                                p.y -= cy;

                                // rotate point
                                float xnew = p.x * c - p.y * s;
                                float ynew = p.x * s + p.y * c;

                                // translate point back:
                                p.x = xnew + cx;
                                p.y = ynew + cy;
                        */

                        // we rotate an ABSOLUTE angle, not the difference
                        double sinx = Math.Sin(rotationBefore);
                        double cosx = Math.Cos(rotationBefore);
                        center.X *= result.Size.X;
                        center.Y *= result.Size.Y;
                        double tmpCenX = cosx * center.X - sinx * center.Y;
                        center.Y = sinx * center.X + cosx * center.Y;
                        center.X = tmpCenX;
                        center += result.Position;
                    }

                    // counting rotation
                    double cos, sin;
                    cos = Math.Cos(result.Rotation - rotationBefore);
                    sin = Math.Sin(result.Rotation - rotationBefore);

                    result.Position.X -= center.X;
                    result.Position.Y -= center.Y;
                    double tmpPosX = cos * result.Position.X - sin * result.Position.Y;
                    result.Position.Y = sin * result.Position.X + cos * result.Position.Y;
                    result.Position.X = tmpPosX;
                    result.Position.X += center.X;
                    result.Position.Y += center.Y;
                }
            }; 

        if (Absolute)
        {
            if (Rotation.HasValue)
            {
                result.Rotation = Rotation.Value;
                HandleRotationOrigin(RotationOrigin);
            }
            if (Position.HasValue)
                result.Position = Position.Value;
            if (Scale.HasValue)
                result.Scale = Scale.Value;                
        }
        else
        {
            if (Rotation.HasValue)
            {
                result.Rotation += Rotation.Value;
                HandleRotationOrigin(RotationOrigin);
            }
            if (Position.HasValue)
                result.Position += Position.Value;
            if (Scale.HasValue)
                result.Scale += Scale.Value;                
        }         

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide some code to show what you mean?

Comment: Can you give more code as an example?

Comment: Why don't you just extract this common logic as a private method?

Comment: Please post some code. But, if you got some code to repeat in many methods, why not create new private methods that contains these "fragments" of code ?

Comment: I thought about using a private method, but I use a lot of local variables and I don't want to pass so many parameters.
This is more of a _how to write code properly_ question than _OMG my code doesn't work, help_ question.

Comment: Looks like nullable abuse to me.  This code is missing an enum.

Comment: _I use a lot of local variables_ sounds like refactoring - aggregate them in struct/classes, abstract operations, create helper classes with static methods an so on.

Comment: @HansPassant
I've actually heard about Nullables only once, on a lecture and that's the way I've been thinking of how to use them :) I'll correct this knowledge I swear :)

Comment: @KonradKokosa
I get your point and I can do nothing but to agree, but I don't really want to create all of these for every method I create. These locals most of the times are present only in one method - just what `result` is here

Comment: In addition to my answer below i'd say the 'reused' functionality probably _should_ be a private method, its large and looks fairly general,  ie you may wish to use it in other methods. i can see a value (which i'd never thought of doing) in naming a two line lamda you're going to use 4 times in one method and nowhere else though and keeping it local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its (nearly) the only way around in a struct (value type),  your code would compile if it was a class.

Also note AS TransformationMod is a struct / value type if you pass it around you'll be copying it and thus your anonymous method (or even a named one) will be operating on a copy,  to avoid this in turn you'd need to pass it with ref, but see [Delegate for an Action< ref T1, T2>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030303/delegate-for-an-action-ref-t1-t2) and read about boxing

I would suggest you probably *want* this to be a class anyway.

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice, clear and thoughtful answer :)