# Passing a method (with ref parameter) as argument

Tags: c#, methods

In my specific use-case I have a couple of places that use `Interlocked.Increment` and `Interlocked.Decrement` interchangeably and so I wanted to consolidated the logic into a single method, and pass the correct method to be invoked, as argument:

```
if (Interlocked.Increment(ref x) == something)
{
    DoThis();
}
else
{
    DoThat();
}
```

And another place where I do:

```
if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref x) == something)
{
    DoThis();
}
else
{
    DoThat();
}
```

And the idea is to consolidate into:

```
void Foo(Action<ref int> interlockedOp)
{
    if (interlockedOp(ref x) == something)
    {
        DoThis();
    }
    else
    {
        DoThat();
    }    
}
```

But the `Action<ref int>` part doesn't compile.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Not with a built-in, you'd have to create your own delegate type, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030303/delegate-for-an-action-ref-t1-t2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if `Action<ref int>` compiled, it wouldn't work. `Increment`/`Decrement` return a value. You're even using the return value. `Func<ref int, int>`, if it compiled, would do it, but you still cannot use `ref` in that context.

With a custom delegate type, it's easy.

```
delegate int InterlockedOp(ref int location);
```

Comment: Yes, I used `Action` by mistake, should have been `Func`. And thank you for showing how to do this with a delegate. Now off to learn about the differences between using a delegate and `Func`/`Action` :)